# Лишнее окно tkinter, как избавиться?

Tags: python, tkinter, окно

Имеется код:

```
# Привет Мир

import tkinter

def f1(my_string):
    def my_printing(word):
        print(word)
        root.destroy()

    button_names = my_string.split()
    root = tkinter.Tk()
    root.attributes('-topmost', True)
    for i in button_names:
        button = tkinter.Button(master=root, text=i, command=lambda i = i: my_printing(i))
        button.pack()
    root.mainloop()

tkinter.Tk().withdraw() #выключаем окно
my_string = tkinter.Tk().clipboard_get() #получаем строку из буфера обмена

if 'Привет' in my_string:
    f1(my_string)
```

Если в буфер обмена попадает фраза "Привет Мир", то должно создаваться окно с кнопками "Привет" и "Мир". При выполнении вышеуказанного кода появляется окно с кнопками на переднем плане и лишнее пустое окно tkinter. Как сделать так, чтобы пустое окно не появлялось?
Пытался воспользоваться конструкцией tkinter.Tk().withdraw():

1. После импорта библиотеки - не помогло;
2. Внутри функции - не помогло;
3. Команда root.withdraw() выключает само окно root.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Каждый вызов `tkinter.Tk()` создает новый объект окна. Одно окно вы создали и сразу скрыли, потом создали еще одно пустое окно в вызове `tkinter.Tk().clipboard_get()`, а потом еще третье в функции `f1`. Итого получается одно скрытое окно и два видимых.

Нужно создать одно окно, скрыть его, проверять состояние буфера обмена через `root.after`, потом отобразить скрытое окно с нужной информацией в функции `f1`:

```
import tkinter


def f1(my_string):
    def my_printing(word):
        print(word)
        root.destroy()

    button_names = my_string.split()

    root.attributes('-topmost', True)
    for i in button_names:
        button = tkinter.Button(master=root, text=i, command=lambda i = i: my_printing(i))
        button.pack()
    
    root.deiconify()  # Отображаем окно
    


def check_clipboard():
    # Проверяем состояние буфера обмена
    try:
        my_string = root.clipboard_get() #получаем строку из буфера обмена
    except tkinter.TclError:  # Если буфер обмена пуст, вылетает исключение TclError
        my_string = ""
    
    if 'Привет' in my_string:
        f1(my_string)
    else:
        root.after(100, check_clipboard)  # Перепроверить через 100 миллисекунд


root = tkinter.Tk()
root.withdraw()  # скрываем окно
check_clipboard()  # Периодически проверяем состояние буфера обмена

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!